# lightning tree grid issue with displaying grand child data from apex

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I have this below query . Where i am trying to display Opportunity name and products associated to it in a lightning tree-grid structure.

The issue i am facing is i am able to display opportunity name . But i am unable to display product name and family

```
 List < Opportunity > opps = [ SELECT Id, Name, StageName,
                ( SELECT Id, Product2.Name, Product2.Family FROM OpportunityLineItems )
                FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN:  oppsIds];
```

HTML -

```
 <lightning-tree-grid hide-checkbox-column columns={gridColumns} data={gridData} key-field="Id">
        </lightning-tree-grid>
```

JS -

```
gridColumns = [{
        type: 'text',
        fieldName: 'Name',
        label: 'Opportunity Name'
    },
    {
        type: 'text',
        fieldName: 'StageName',
        label: 'Stage'
    },
    {
        type: 'text',
        fieldName: 'Product2.Name',
        label: 'ProductName'

    },
    {
        type: 'text',
        fieldName: 'Product2.Family',
        label: 'Product Family'

    }
    ];
```

wire method returning the data

```
 gridColumns = [{
    type: 'text',
    fieldName: 'Name',
    label: 'Opportunity Name'
},
{
    type: 'text',
    fieldName: 'StageName',
    label: 'Stage'
},
{
    type: 'text',
    fieldName: 'Product2.Name',
    label: 'Product Name'

},
{
    type: 'text',
    fieldName: 'Product2.Family',
    label: 'Product Family'

}
];
gridData
allRows
@api recordId
@wire(fetchOLIs, { contractId: '$recordId' })
olitreedata({ error, data }) {
    if ( data ) {
  
       // this.gridData = tempData;
        this.gridData = data.map((row) => {
            row = { ...row }; // copy row object
            const items = row.OpportunityLineItems; // Save items
            delete row.OpportunityLineItems; // remove from row
            row._children = items.map((item) => this.flattenObject(item)); // flatten item
            return row;
          });

    } else if ( error ) {
     


    }
}

flattenObject(object, result = {}, path = []) {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
      if (typeof value === "object") {
        flattenObject(value, result, [...path, key]);
      } else {
        result[`${path.join(".")}${path.length ? "." : ""}${key}`] = value;
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The various lightning list items (e.g. treeGrid) do not automatically navigate objects. In other words, given the field name `Product2.Family`, treeGrid and datatable expect data that looks like this:

```
[ { 'Product2.Family': 'Software' } ]
```

But you have data that looks like this:

```
[ { Product2: { Family: 'Software' } } ]
```

You have to manually flatten those objects using a method like this:

```
function flattenObject(object, result = {}, path = []) {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
    if (typeof value === "object") {
      flattenObject(value, result, [...path, key]);
    } else {
      result[`${path.join(".")}${path.length ? "." : ""}${key}`] = value;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Which you then use in your wire handler:

```
if (data) {
  this.allRows = data.map((row) => {
    row = { ...row }; // copy row object
    const items = row.OpportunityLineItems; // Save items
    delete row.OpportunityLineItems; // remove from row
    row._children = items.map((item) => flattenObject(item)); // flatten item
    return row;
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi sfdcfox.. I am getting this error .."Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: LWC component's @wire target property or method threw an error during value provisioning. Original error:"  at line .. "result[`${path.join(".")}${path.length ? "." : ""}${key}`] = value;"

Comment: i have updated my js file above

Comment: got the issue.. forgot to add this. flattenObject inside the function

Comment: Thank u sfdcfox..

Comment: @hellraizer I was actually implying the function be outside the class, see [demo](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/jkz8zbW1wCrlzBsBM7iq/src/app.js?p=stories).

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox - can we flatten the data using [imperative apex calls](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex_call_imperative)?

Comment: @Mahmood That method I wrote should work on any data. For imperative calls: `this.data = flattenObject(await serverCall(params));` or `serverCall(params).then((result)=>{ this.data = flattenObject(result) })`.

Comment: @Mahmood Or if you mean, can you flatten it in Apex directly? You can, but I'd argue that this is never as efficient as using JS directly.

Comment: @sfdcfox - no I have flattened the data in apex using wrapper eventually but could not do so in JS as I was not using @wire function, instead I am using Imperative call. Seemed like flattening in JS only works with `@wire`.