# LWC get parent data in lightning-datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I am trying to flatten the @wire decorator so i can get __r fields into my datatable, and I am failing miserably

let me show you what i have tried, none of which has worked

try 1: mapping

```
columns = [
    { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name' },
    { label: 'Household Name', fieldName: 'HouseholdName'}
];
@api recordId;
householdTags;
@wire(getData, {FundInterestPriorityId: '$recordId'})
wiredContacts({ error, data }) {
    if (this.data) {
                this.data = this.data.map(row=>{
                    return{...row, HouseholdName: row.ucinn_ascendv2__Account__r.Name}
                })
    
                this.householdTags = this.data;
```

try 2: object / array mapping

```
if (this.data) {
            let preparedAssets = [];
            this.data.forEach(asset => {
            let preparedAsset = {};
            preparedAsset.Name = asset.Name;
            preparedAsset.HouseholdName = asset.ucinn_ascendv2__Account__r.Name;
            preparedAssets.push(preparedAsset);
            window.console.log(preparedAssets)

            });
            this.data = preparedAssets;

            this.householdTags = this.data;
```

my html

```
<lightning-datatable
key-field="id"
data={householdTags}
columns={columns}>
</lightning-datatable>
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

```
if(this.data) {
  this.data = this.data...
```

Which is never set. You meant:

```
if(data) {
  this.data = data...
```

Keep in mind that `this` means you're trying to access the component's properties, while without `this`, it means you're accessing a locally defined or static variable (one outside the class or imported).

P.S. I wrote a function that automates the [flattening process](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/379451/2984) so you don't have to keep reinventing the wheel every time.

Comment: updated that piece but still does not fix the issue

Comment: @JayRizzi Please edit your question to show the updated code, I'll take another look.