# Custom fields are not getting query from Custom Object after installing a 2GP managed package

Tags: managed-package, 2gp

I have created a 2GP-managed package that includes an Apex class with SOQL queries. But from one SOQL query, which is on a custom object, I am unable to get the data for custom fields from that custom object. I am able to get standard fields from that same custom object.
I am just getting blank fields in the Lightning data table.

[image]

​​​​​​​

Comment: - You may have not granted the appropriate field-level security for your custom fields in your package. You need to ensure that the profile or permission set that you are using to access the custom object has read access to the custom fields.

Comment: Thank you for your respone @TusharJadav I have given read and write permissions for all custom fields on that custom object . But still iam facing that isssue.

Comment: Make sure that you have records on the custom object that you have queried into the apex.

Comment: Yes I have records. I have added the Lightning data table screenshot in above. can you please check once.

Comment: @Phil W can you please help me on this.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/379451/2984)? It may answer your question.

Comment: No @sfdcfox . In that its problem with nested object field in lightning tree grid. But here iam unable to see straight forward custom field from custom object by using query.

Comment: Are you remembering to account for your namespace? make sure you're using `import FIELD_NAME from '@salesforce/schema/ObjectName.FieldName` and referencing that field in your column definitions, such as `{ label: 'Whatever', fieldName: FIELD_NAME.fieldApiName }`.

Comment: Iam just assigning like this   {
      label: "Status",
      fieldName: "Workbench_Status__c",
      type: "text",
      initialWidth: 180
    },
    {
      label: "In Use",
      fieldName: "Used__c",
      type: "boolean",
      initialWidth: 70
    } like how we generally give columns to lightning data table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Lightning Datatable Columns, you have missed to add your namespace to the API Name of the fields.

For Example, if your namespace is "testingabc". Any custom field added in the package will have api name as testingabc__fieldapiname__c.

Try adding the datatable columns like this:

```
[
{ 
      label: "Status", 
      fieldName: "namespace__Workbench_Status__c", 
      type: "text", 
      initialWidth: 180 
}, 
{ 
      label: "In Use", 
      fieldName: "namespace__Used__c", 
      type: "boolean", 
      initialWidth: 70 
}
]
```

Comment: Thank you So much  @S1th Yeshwanth. It got resolved.